# XML parsing with attributes that is empty (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

i have an xml file with attributes like this:

```
  <folder name = 'somename' description = ''/>
```

i want to display the description attribute as 'null' but it force closes and throws a FATAL Exception main in the LogCat.

i have this code below at the startElement() method

```
   if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("folder")) {
      /** Get attribute value */
      if(attributes.getValue("description")== "null"){
         parseList.setFolderdesc(null);
      }else{
         String desc = attributes.getValue("description");                   
         parseList.setFolderdesc(desc);
      }
```

i tried this code but no luck...
how will i solve this without changing my xml file?

Comment: i used SaxParser here from the example at androidpeople.com

Comment: your problem is not detailed enough. what are you trying to do and why when does it force close?

Comment: so it force close on parseList.setFolderdesc(null); ?

Comment: that because it cant be set to null object.. just use something different then .. for example set a Boolean to false and then on the display part - if its false then don't display  .. or some other clever maneuver. this force close is totally legit and doesn't relate to your XML ..

Comment: It would help if you told us what exception is being thrown ... as reported by LogCat.

Comment: i solved the null display, but i guess it force closes because the other parent tags don't have a <folder name = 'somename' description= ''> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the following code

```
String desc = null;
        try{
        desc = attributes.getValue("description");
        if((desc == null) || (desc.length()<=0)){
            desc = null;    
        }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            desc = null;
        }
if(parseList != null){
parseList.setFolderdesc(desc);  
}
```

Comment: Uggh.  Your belt-and-braces exception handling is going to obscure any bugs.  Catching Exception is evil ... just don't do it!!

Comment: @nhqdualcagony - it might "work", but it is extremely bad practice to catch `Exception`.  For instance, if `attributes` itself was `null` due to some bug in your code, then Sunil's code would make it difficult for you to find that bug.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks for your effort. I know it is not the good to catch Exception But it is not bad always. in some case eg if you want to so generic error message to the user irrespective of any type of Exception i that case you have to handle catch.

Comment: @All, Also I feel Handle Catch in outermost layer (calling environment) if possible.

Comment: @SunilKumarSahoo - I'll grant you that case.  But your example is not that case.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't do what you expect:

```
  if (attributes.getValue("description") == "null") {
```

You are comparing the attribute value with the String `"null"` not with a java `null`.  (And you are testing strings the unsafe way too!  Strings should be tested for equality using `String.equals()` not the `==` operator.)

That test should be written as follows:

```
  if (attributes.getValue("description") == null) {
```

or better still:

```
  if (attributes.getValue("description") == null || 
      attributes.getValue("description").isEmpty()) {
```

(I'm not sure whether this will fix you problem, because I don't understand your problem description.)